# OSMdroid could not find class GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I have been creating my own osmdroid apk from svn, i have checkouted. Using this howto: mappingdev.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/166/ I have been able to create jar file from Osmdroid and include it in my Android application. Problem is, I am geting warnings, when my application starts.

> 09-21 16:09:08.465: E/dalvikvm(23563): Could not find class 'org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint', referenced from method com.globaler.app.Poi.fillFromCursor
>
> 09-21 16:09:08.470: W/dalvikvm(23563): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/osmdroid/util/BoundingBoxE6;)
>
> 09-21 16:09:08.470: I/dalvikvm(23563): Could not find method org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBoxE6.getLatSouthE6, referenced from method com.globaler.app.Poi.getInRectangle
>
> 09-21 16:09:08.470: W/dalvikvm(23563): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10324: Lorg/osmdroid/util/BoundingBoxE6;.getLatSouthE6 ()I

What am I doing wrong? Other methods seems accepted, only theese are not. Your help will be appreciated

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a linkage issue.

You have to ensure that your jar file is properly copied under the `/lib` directory of your project **AND** added to the build path.

Should you be using Eclipse/ADT, you should upgrade to the latest version (Juno, released on Jun 24th 2014, at the time I am writing this). It takes care of the linkage automatically once the jar files are under /lib.

Should your app be obfuscated, this may also be a ProGuard issue. In that case please let me know, there's already a SO question regarding this.